# Download files(.gz) from a bucket using C#

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm able to use gsutil to download my files, now I need to automate this process my initial option is use C# API is that possible? Any Idea or best practice on how to schedule a process to download the .gz files daily (can be using gsutil)?

My goal is import my data into the SQL server db.

Thanks
Leandro

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no C# API for Google Cloud Storage.

Since you said using gsutil is an option, could you set up a cron job that is run daily? More specifically, write a short shell script that contains the command(s) to run gsutil with the necessary options to download objects as appropriate, then add that script to your crontab with the `@daily` qualifier.